creating a discord account using the discord api
Sorry if my English is approximate, I am using a translator. I recently tried to create a program to automatically create a Discord account using their API. For solving the captcha, I am using the Anticaptcha API, but every time my code gives me the error "sitekey-secret-mismatch" even though on my Anticaptcha dashboard the captcha has been solved successfully. I am almost sure that the sitekey is correct.
Here is my code:
from anticaptchaofficial.hcaptchaproxyless import hCaptchaProxyless

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
}

url_register = "https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/register"

user_data = {
    "email": "cling-uncurled-gem@duck.com",
    "username": "qsdkfjkjhskddf",
    "password": "@1cling-uncurled-gem",
    "date_of_birth": "2000-01-01",
    "consent": True,
    "gift_code_sku_id": None,
    "captcha_key": None
}

def solve_hcaptcha(sitekey, url):
    solver = hCaptchaProxyless()
    solver.set_verbose(1)
    solver.set_key('my_anticaptcha_api_key')
    solver.set_website_url(url)
    solver.set_website_key(sitekey)
    
    captcha_solution = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
    if captcha_solution != 0:
        return captcha_solution
    else:
        print("Impossible de résoudre le CAPTCHA")
        return None

captcha_sitekey = '4c672d35-0701-42b2-88c3-78380b0db560'
discord_url = "https://discord.com/register"

captcha_solution = solve_hcaptcha(captcha_sitekey, discord_url)

if captcha_solution:
    print("CAPTCHA solution:", captcha_solution)
    user_data["captcha_key"] = captcha_solution

    print("User Data:", user_data)

    response = requests.post(url_register, headers=headers, json=user_data)

    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response JSON:", response.json())
else:
    print("Échec de la résolution du CAPTCHA")```

Here is the full error:
Status Code: 400
Response JSON: {'captcha_key': ['sitekey-secret-mismatch'], 'captcha_sitekey': '4c672d35-0701-42b2-88c3-78380b0db560', 'captcha_service': 'hcaptcha'}


